# How to use BCGControlBar debug DLLs in my release EXE

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I wanna build a MFC project with the famous BCGControlBar library. I can download the evaluation version BCG from its website and the free-to-download package only contains the debug DLLs. I want to use this debug version BCGControlBar to build with my release EXE. I changed the alerts in BCGBProInc.h to stop the "BCGControlBar PRO release mode is not available in the Evaluation version" message. But error occurs when exe running: "BCGTest2.exe has stopped working.". Here're the problem details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: BCGTest2.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.1
  Application Timestamp:    52e7d79e
  Fault Module Name:    mfc100u.dll
  Fault Module Version: 10.0.40219.325
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4df2e0e6
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 002577bf
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    2052
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Is it possible to use BCGControlBar debug DLLs in my release EXE? Thx.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to mix MFC using object files that are compiled in debug mode together with object files in release mode.

The binary images don't match. The vtables don't match... Use both in release or both in Debug mode.